# NavController sharedTransition RecyclerView item to Fragment not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, uinavigationcontroller, transition

So I've read all the articles and examples on `sharedTransitions` I could find and it seemed simple enough, but for some reason it doesn't work for me.

This is my `RecyclerView.Item` layout:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/LibraryItem">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/library_note_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:transitionName="@string/library_item_transition"
                style="@style/LibraryImage"/>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This is the `onClickListener` action for the `RecyclerView` items in my first `Fragment`:

```
private fun startEditNoteFragment(view: View) {
            val action = LibraryFragmentDirections.actionEditNote()
            val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(view to view.transitionName)

            findNavController().navigate(action, extras)
        }
```

Note: I tried using the destination `Fragment` id instead of the `action`, also tried making the action transition animations from `none` to something else. Nothing worked.

This is the edit `Fragment` (the one we're transitioning to) layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.ink.edit.drawing.view.PathRenderingView
            android:id="@+id/pathRenderingView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:transitionName="@string/library_item_transition"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here's the transition code in the `Fragment`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        sharedElementEnterTransition = TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)
    }
```

Note: I also tried doing `postponeEnterTransition()` in `onCreate` and `startPostponedEnterTransition()` in `onCreateView` and still nothing.

I'm testing on Pixel 3 with Android 9, the project's `minSdkVersion` is 21, `buildToolsVersion` is 28.0.3. Navigation library dependencies are `navigation-fragment-ktx:2.0.0` and `navigation-ui-ktx:2.0.0`

---

*Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or missing?*

Comment: transition names must be unique on the view hierarchy and it looks like you are adding many elements with the same transition name (as many as items you have in the recycler view)

Comment: @dmarin i've used shared element Transition in a RecyclerView, and it has not caused issues that all inflated item have the same transition name(the inflated view itself in the RecyclerView is unique), i also had the same issue when i used it with the Navigation Library..

Comment: @dmarin is correct. When I left only one view in the adapter, the animation worked. You can post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transition names must be unique on the view hierarchy and it looks like you are adding many elements with the same transition name (as many as items you have in the recycler view)

Comment: This guide helped me correct my code https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html?m=1